# How to read an XML .osm file with Python

Tags: python, openstreetmap

I have an OSM XML file on local drive that I want to read with Python to do further tasks. I have tried something like this but it doesn't work.

```
import ogr
import shapely
from shapely.geometry import *    

driver=ogr.GetDriverByName('OSM')
data = driver.Open('file.osm')
layer = data.GetLayer('points')

features=[x for x in layer]
print (len(features))
```

Comment: [Extracting and Converting OpenStreetMap data in Python](http://andrewgaidus.com/Convert_OSM_Data/)  for example

Comment: I tried to that but I get this error message:
    driver=ogr.GetDriverByName('OSM')
AttributeError: module 'ogr' has no attribute 'GetDriverByName'

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any additional information and requested clarifications.

Comment: This is the message I get after runing the script:  

`Traceback (most recent call last):  

  File "D:\test.py", line 7, in <module>  
    driver=ogr.GetDriverByName('OSM')  
AttributeError: module 'ogr' has no attribute 'GetDriverByName'`

Comment: Thne ogr is not properly installed,

Comment: @gene What do you suggest as solution?

Comment: I don't know your Python installation (see [Python GDAL/OGR cookbook:Vector Layers](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html))